# Angularjs jsonp causes unexpected errors

Tags: html, angularjs, mainframe

mainpage.html

```
app.controller('espn', function($scope,$http){
$http.jsonp("http://www.mfrm.von.com/v1/sports")
   .success( function(data,status,headers,config){
      alert("success");
      console.log(data);
      console.log(status);
   })
   .error( function(data,status,headers,config){
      alert("error");
      console.log(data);
      console.log(status);
   });
});
```

Webservice Consumer url: 
          http://localhost:8080/angularjs/app?abc=123&phon=876

webservice provider(mainframe) url:
          http://www.mfrm.von.com/v1/sports

We faced the issues:
           Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Is there a possibility to do with the UI(Angularjs) with out using java code?

Angularjs version 1.4.0

Provider part giving response json object.

is (provider) Mainframe can able to configure the cors ability?

Thanks and please correct me

output printing as error method only

Comment: this may help https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$exceptionHandler

Comment: Please post a plunker (http://plnkr.co) of your code. There is insufficient code here to identify the error.